# Firebase Security Rules completely open but still giving permission denied error

Tags: security, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, flutter

I've written these Security Rules for my Firebase permissions that from what I understand should give all authenticated user permissions to read and write...

```
{
 "rules": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
  ".write": "auth != null"
}
}
```

But I still got these errors on my RTDB nodes..

```
[Firebase/Database][I-RDB03812] Listener at /UserVideo/null failed: permission_denied
[Firebase/Database][I-RDB03812] Listener at /users/4eb8920a-e407-4488-bce4-c6f64f7b0891 failed: permission_denied
```

I've validated that `4eb8920a-e407-4488-bce4-c6f64f7b0891` is in fact the users uid.  And my Security Simulator told me both read and write were allowed for my ref/users and ref/UserVideo.  What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps you're not authenticated? Try `true` instead of `"auth != null"` to check.

Comment: I would suggest checking, and maybe even posting, your code - specifically where you authenticate and see if it's returning an error when you are authenticating.

Comment: As a note you are trying to attach a listener to */UserVideo/null* which may be a clue to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try auth.uid instead:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null"
    }
}
```

Comment: *".read": "auth != null",* is a default setting provided by Firebase so auth.uid won't make any difference.